# Apache2.2 -> Apache2.4: The image extension cannot be obtained

Tags: php, apache, symfony

The application that was running on Apache2.2/CentOS6.7 has been moved to Apache2.4/CentOS Stream environment.
When I checked the operation of image saving, I could not get the image, and when I checked it with the developer tools, the following error occurred in Network->Response.
Looking at the error, I couldn't get the extension, but it worked in Apache 2.2, so   it's weird.
Is there anything to consider?
I think it doesn't matter, but before the migration, I put the source code in `/home/vagrant/Symfony`. Currently, the source code is located in `home/www/Symfony`.

Error

```
Warning: getimagesize(home/www/Symfony/src/../../../../public/image_url_ori.): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

ImageService

```php
    public function saveImage(Image $image)
    {
        //Set extension
        $ext = $image->getImageExtension();
        if (!$ext && $image->getFileUpload()) {
            $ext = $image->getFileUpload()->guessExtension();
            $image->setImageExtension($ext);
        }

        $suffix = "_ori";
        $image->setFileName(date('YmdHis') . '_' . mt_rand() . $suffix . '.' . $ext);

    }
```

Image.php

```php
    public function setFileName($fileName)
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    public function setImageTypeByFilePath($path)
    {
        $info = getimagesize($path);

        if (isset($info[2])) {
            $this->imageType = $info[2];
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function postUpload()
    {
        $path = $shopYearDir . '/' . $this->fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageExtension
     *
     * @param string $attachedFileExtension
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setImageExtension($ext)
    {
        $this->imageExtension = $ext;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImageExtension()
    {
        return $this->imageExtension;
    }

    public function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../../../public/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    private function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads';
    }
```

UtillImage.php

```php
    private $filePath;
    private $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png','swf');

    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->filePath = $path;
        $info = getimagesize($path);
        $this->imageHeight = $info[1];
        $this->type = $this->types[$info[2]];
        $this->ext = $info['extension'];
    }
    public function save()
    {
        if ($this->type == 'jpeg') {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->filePath);
        }
        $path = $this->dir . '/' . $this->name . '.' . $this->ext;
        if ($this->type == 'jpeg') {
            imagejpeg($newImage, $path, $this->quality);
        }
```

Comment: I would guess that the issue is a server configuration one, not an apache version issue. 
Try to use the absolute path for the image and check that the path is correct

Comment: So I guess you uploaded your image on your server and then it say :  "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".
I think that the problem is with your path which may be incorrect or with the upload which have failed. Can you check if the image is well uploaded on your server and compare with the ``$path``

Comment: @Nathanael There was no problem with the contents of path. However, I think the problem is that ```$ext``` is null and the extension cannot be obtained.

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE The situation is that it cannot be saved because ```$ext``` cannot be obtained with ```$image->setFileName```. There seems to be no problem with the contents of ```$path``` except that there is no extension.

Comment: Probably not related to Apache 2.2 / 2.4. Check PHP version, also check whether GD and Imagick extension have been installed and enabled or not (via `phpinfo()` or look into `php.ini`)

Comment: PROBLEM: after upgrading your system, Symfony [guessExtension()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php#method_getExtension) is returning "null", instead of a valid file extension (like your application used to return, before the update).  I would agree with Nathanael - it's probably *NOT* an "Apache version" issue, nor necessarily a "CentOS" issue.  I would your check 1) Symfony, and 2) PHP versions/configuration first.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for your comment. Certainly GD was used before the migration, but it was not reflected in the migration destination. I installed it and confirmed that it was enabled with ```phpinfo ()```, but the same error was output.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for your comment. As advised, I checked the Symfony packages and PHP modules, but they were all migrated.

Comment: Do you really have a folder structure with that list of .. directories? You are mixing absolute and relative path and that’s the error you are facing

Comment: `getimagesize(home/www/Symfony/src/../../../../public/image_url_ori.)` - does that file even exist?

Comment: @LelioFaieta There is a directory. Even if you specify the absolute path ```/home/www/ahi /portal/Symfony/public```, the same error will be returned. Conversely, if you specify an appropriate root in ```getUploadRootDir()```, you will get the error ```The directory cannot be created```.

Comment: @NicoHaase The file does not exist. If it works as expected, the system will save files with extensions such as ```image_url_ori.jpeg```.